# not value after changes from angularjs $watch

Tags: angularjs

In my angularjs directive I have used the following code to detect changes in this and execute function as follows

```
$scope.$watch(angular.bind(this, function () {
                    return this.dat;
                }), function (newVal) {
         })
```

and In my main controller I am calling the directive as follows

```
<line dat=ctrl.testdata></line>
```

Inside my main controller I have defined ctrl.testdata as follows

```
 self.testdata = {};
 self.testdata.dat = [ {'sdfds':'bbbb','sdfsd','lll'}]
 self.testdata.k = {
   "c": ["0y", "w6"],
   "rs": ["n", "i"]
}
```

the newVal is changing when testdata.dat is changing but it is not changing when testdata.k is changing how do I proceed thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default watch check only object equality - your test data same, when you edit it's props; You can use another binding, keeping this in mind, or use deep equality(poor performance);

```
$scope.$watch(angular.bind(this, function () {
                    return this.dat;
                }), function (newVal) {
         }, true)
```

Comment: I have one small problem now that testdata.dat gets repeated many times how do I stop that

Comment: Don't understand your problem? Could you describe it clearer or show codepen.io